# Why it's showing underline eventhough I import necessary package in Katalon Studio?

Tags: point, katalon-studio, katalon

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Point

// Define the two TestObjects to be swapped
TestObject firstObject = new TestObject("firstObject")
firstObject.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[@id='firstObject']") 

TestObject secondObject = new TestObject("secondObject")
secondObject.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[@id='secondObject']")

// Get the locations of the TestObjects before the swap
Point firstLocationBefore = firstObject.getLocation()
Point secondLocationBefore = secondObject.getLocation()
```

Eventhough I import necessary package at top: `import org.openqa.selenium.Point`

But it's still showing underline for `getLocation()` in the code.

Why it's showing underline eventhough I import necessary package in Katalon Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getLocation()` method is a member of the `WebElement` class in the Selenium library. Therefore, in order to use `getLocation()`, I need to create a `WebElement` object and then call `getLocation()` on that object. My code only have two TestObjects, so I can't use `getLocation()` method.

To fix this code, I need to create a `WebElement object` and then call the `getLocation()` method on it:

```
WebElement element = DriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='firstObject']"));`
Point firstLocationBefore = element.getLocation();
```